# Powershell extract CPU, Memory and Free Disc space from servers

Tags: powershell

I am actually working as an intern in a company, my supervisor is looking for a PowerShell script that will install on each customer's server. It will extract this information about each server: Free Disc space and Windows update that have been installed. This script needs to execute automatically each 2 weeks and send a PDF report by mail (The report needs to be like the picture below). Information to extract

For now all I did is the script to extract Free Space on each HDD:

```
$Filter = @{Expression={$_.Name};Label="DiskName"}, `
          @{Expression={[int]$($_.Freespace/1GB)};Label="FreeSpaceGB"} 
Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume | Format-Table $Filter -AutoSize
```

I found a command to get a scope of Windows Updates that have been installed:

```
$wsus.GetUpdateCount($updatescope)
```

But this command is not working, I am getting this error:

> Can not call a method in a Null expression. The character line: 1: 1 +
>   $ Wsus.GetSummariesPerUpdate ( $ updatescope , $ computerscope ) +
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~ +
>   CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation ( :) [] , RuntimeException +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Ps: I am a beginner with PowerShell your help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How are you populating `$wsus` as this is not a system variable by default.

Comment: I found it when I was googling the output for this commande is only a number of updates installed and that's what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I use the code below to get Local Disk Drive information

```
Get-WMIobject win32_LogicalDisk -computername localhost -filter "DriveType=3" | Select-Object SystemName,DeviceID,@{Name="Size(GB)";Expression={"{0:N1}" -    f($_.size/1gb)}},
@{Name="FreeSpace(GB)";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.freespace/1gb)}},
@{Name="% FreeSpace(GB)";Expression={"{0:N2}%" -f(($_.freespace/$_.size)*100)}}
```